# Write custom code analysis tool for Python/Pydev?

Tags: python, code-analysis

What is the easiest way to write a code analysis tool where I can issue warnings on some custom possible design flaws in the program? Most warnings I'm thinking of are OOP related.

Ideally I would write a plugin for some already existing parser and integrate it in Eclipse/Pydev. Can I extend pylint conveniently? Or is there some aid from Pydev?

What is the most effortless way?

Comment: You might want to check out [the ``ast`` module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html) in the python standard library - you can hook in with the code already parsed down to a nice level.

Comment: I'll definitely look at it at some point. I was hoping for an easier solution though, that also easily integrates with Pydev.

Comment: I'd take a look at http://pypy.org/. The actual interpreter is written in a subset of Python, and you can start from that and modify it, replacing or adding code at any point you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend PyDev itself: grab its code and do some analysis with it. At the code-level: com.python.pydev.analysis.OccurrencesAnalyzer is the starting place (to get the code: http://www.pydev.org/developers.html).

It already has ways of parsing the code to get the AST with a visitor structure you can use for the analysis.

For simpler checks you could just improve upon the pep8.py that's distributed in PyDev itself (/org.python.pydev/pysrc/third_party/pep8/pep8.py).